# Dynkin's formula, $dX_{t}=b(X_{t})\,dt+\sigma (X_{t})\,dB_{t}$ or $dX_{t}=b(t, X_{t})\,dt+\sigma (t, X_{t})\,dB_{t}$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Wiki page of [Dynkin's formla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin%27s_formula) says:

> Let $X$ be the $R^n$-valued Itō diffusion solving the stochastic
> differential equation
>
> $$\mathrm {d} X_{t}=b(X_{t})\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (X_{t})\,\mathrm{d} B_{t}.$$
>
> Let $A$ be the infinitesimal generator of $X$, defined by its action
> on compactly-supported $C^2$ (twice differentiable with continuous
> second derivative) functions $f : Rn → R$ as
> $$Af(x)=\lim_{t\downarrow 0}{\frac {\mathbf {E} ^{x}[f(X_{t})]-f(x)}{t}}$$
>
> Then Dynkin's formula holds:
> $$ \mathbf {E} ^{x}[f(X_{\tau})]=f(x)+\mathbf {E} ^{x}\left[\int _{0}^{\tau }Af(X_{s})\,\mathrm {d}s\right].$$

I'm confused here : does Dynkin's formula only applies to $\mathrm {d} X_{t}=b(X_{t})\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (X_{t})\,\mathrm{d} B_{t}$, or it also works for

$$\mathrm {d} X_{t}=b(t, X_{t})\,\mathrm {d} t+\sigma (t, X_{t})\,\mathrm{d} B_{t}$$

?

On user1's answer that infinitesimal generator are defined only on time-homogeneous Ito diffusions, I don't agree.

Below is from Stochastic Processes in Polymeric Fluids by HC Öttinger.

First on p74 a general infinitesimal generator is defined:
[image]

Then on p76 it specifically refers to Wiener process as time homogeneous example:
[image]

Also, infinitesimal generator is widely used to prove Kolmogorov equations, which are not limited to time homogeneous processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the index ${}_t$ in all the right places and you'll see the proof goes through.

Alternatively, apply the homogenous result to the homogeneous space time process associated to your inhomogeneous process.